# Optimize loop multiple variables

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I have tons of data and I need to optimize this lines but i simply do not know how ...

Some lines of "x" will be black so I don't know how to use arrays without including this blank lines or how to write them without them.

x,a,b & d are variable numbers.

```
a = Sheets("MODULOS").Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row
b = Sheets("TODO").Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To b
Range("Z1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(x, 0).Select

For i = 1 To (a - 1)

If ActiveCell.Value <> 0 Then
    d = Sheets("AGREGADO").Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("AGREGADO").Cells(d + 1, 1).Value = Sheets("TODO").Cells(x + 1, 7).Value
    Sheets("AGREGADO").Cells(d + 1, 3).Value = Sheets("TODO").Cells(x + 1, 25 + i).Value
    Sheets("AGREGADO").Cells(d + 1, 2).Value = Sheets("TODO").Cells(1, 25 + i).Value
    Sheets("AGREGADO").Cells(d + 1, 4).Value = Sheets("TODO").Cells(x + 1, 33 + a).Value
End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Next i
Next x
```

Comment: Why don't you do this with an in-cell formula instead of VBA?

Comment: Im using this data for another things.

Comment: Why would that be a problem with formulas?

Comment: NB: Your title says "optimize", but your code does not work correctly, so that is not optimization you need, but fixing.

Comment: This is a small part of the whole process,everything works fine but this takes too much time.

Comment: My code works fine it just takes too much time if I add the 4th line.

Comment: Can you give example data, and what you expect as output? NB: `a` and `b` don't have values, so this code just does not run as it stands.

Comment: My rawdata changes everytime and there are more lines (variable b) and more colums(variable a) to take care of.
The variables a and b come from another sheet in here i just need to take input of each cell and transfer it to another sheet.

Comment: Is the current sheet "TODO" or still another sheet?

Comment: TODO is the actual sheet, AGREGADO is where i want to put the data but there are more.
Just added where a and b come from.

Comment: Quick optimize: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual` , `Application.ScreenUpdating = False ` at the begining and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic `, `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` before exit.

Comment: Perfect with  --> xlCalculateManual , Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Thank you.

Comment: check the "Read/Write Large Blocks of Cells in a Single Operation" part https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/excel-tips-for-optimizing-performance-obstructions#read-and-write-large-blocks-of-data-in-a-single-operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few way to make your code faster:

Summary (ranked by importance):

1. dis-activate Automatic Calculation and screen updating (as in the
   comment from Tomjohnriddle)
2. Avoid the *.Select* and *ActiveCell*
3. Use WITH where possible when working with objects

In your code it would look like this:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ra As Range

a = Sheets("MODULOS").Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row
b = Sheets("TODO").Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To b

ra = Cells(1 + x, 26)

With Sheets("AGREGADO")

For i = 1 To (a - 1)

If ra.Value <> 0 Then
    d = Sheets("AGREGADO").Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(d + 1, 1).Value = Sheets("TODO").Cells(x + 1, 7).Value
    .Cells(d + 1, 3).Value = Sheets("TODO").Cells(x + 1, 25 + i).Value
    .Cells(d + 1, 2).Value = Sheets("TODO").Cells(1, 25 + i).Value
    .Cells(d + 1, 4).Value = Sheets("TODO").Cells(x + 1, 33 + a).Value
End If

    ra = Cells(1 + x, 26 + 1)

Next i
Next x

End With
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```